# IPad resets when running Time Profiler in Instruments

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I try to run the Time Profiler on my iPad 2(5.0.1) on Xcode 4.2 and it resets as soon as the record tries to begin.Allocation Instrument works,though.
What could the reason be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by Jailbreak on my device)